# Django model, how to auto-increment an object's value

Tags: python, django

So I have this Django model.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
```

I would like the views attribute, to have an auto randomly generated number. So something like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)

    def auto_views(self):
        return randint(0,200)
```

and the views attribute will automatically take the value of the auto_views() function when creating a new product. In the same way as an auto-slug would work.

Comment: "*I would like the views attribute, to have an auto randomly generated number.*". A *random* number?

Comment: yes, like a number between 0 and 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a callable for the default:

```
from random import randint


def auto_views():
    return randint(0, 200)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=auto_views, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **override** default save method to assign a random value when creating object like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding:
            # or using auto_views function
            # self.views = auto_views()
            self.views = randint(0,200)
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**self._state.adding** used for checking object is creating or not. See documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading).